# TSQL Inserting from a temptable where a column might not exist

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, t-sql, ado.net

So I'm trying to insert from one table to another, because I am working with multiple versions of the software I am working on it's possible the temptable I want to insert from won't have the column that I need to insert from, so I wrote the following case statement to handle this:

```
select CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (select * 
                 from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 where table_name like '#tempStatusTable%' 
                   and COLUMN_NAME like '%EmploymentType%') 
    THEN [EmploymentType]
    ELSE -1 
    END
FROM #tempStatusTable t
```

however this results in the error:

> Invalid column name 'EmploymentType'

.

Is there a way to do this kind of thing in SQL?

Comment: is the error message not clear enough?

Comment: Looks like you need Dynamic SQL

Comment: Something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376449)?

Comment: @vkp the error message makes sense, I just don't know why it's happening, that block of code will not be executed unless the case statement is true, so why does the interpreter care? For some reason similar logic works when doing that kind of thing in the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lad2025

sp_executesql lets you do whatever you want so you can execute blocks like that.